# Building web pages for mobile devices that allow dragging

Tags: jquery, html, drag

I want to provide the mobile user (e.g. iPhone, Android, etc...) of my web page the ability to use a slider (like the jQuery slider, for instance).

I cooked up an [example](http://www.vbrad.com/robot.htm).  If you use it in Safari on the iPhone, when you try to drag the slider, it thinks you are dragging the entire page, so that does not work.  On the Android, the slider just simply doesn't move, though both devices support simply clicking on the slider.

So is there a way to build web pages that support dragging, like I want to?

Comment: I'm not actually sure this is possible - i think mobile safari only fires onMouseDown when you _lift_ your finger and then immediately fires the other mouse events... but i'd be very interested to see if it can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the jquery mobile library. Specifically this [slider demo](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/forms/forms-slider.html)

Comment: HTML5 has a slider?? Does it have everything we need to do? we'll all be out of jobs at this rate! :D More seriously though, are you aware of a way to get general dragging to work on mobile safari?

Comment: Oh man, you are a saver.  That's exactly what I needed.  I actually tried the HTML5 input type="range" but couldn't make it work on the mobile devices and just assumed it simply wasn't implemented yet.  Obviously I did something wrong.